# what ever the type given using dom for an input i am getting only type text only in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var datesTxt = document.getElementById("evt_date_txt");
var txt = document.createTextNode("Date:");
datesTxt.appendChild(txt);
var datesInput = document.getElementById("evt_date_input1");
var input      = document.createElement("input");
input.type     = "date";
input.name     = "once_date";
datesInput.appendChild(input);
```

```html
<td><label id="evt_date_txt"></label></td>
<td id="evt_date_input1"></td>
```

I am creating a date type dynamically using onchange with select ,but only text input is created .i have also given input type="date" even though i am only getting text input.

Comment: What makes you think it's not a date input? (Until you focus them, on some browsers they look a lot like text inputs.) Does the browser you're running this on support date inputs?

Comment: I've extracted the relevant code into this fiddle; creates a date input for me on Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/6519eftg/

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. The question has nothing to do with PHP. I've removed the tag for you.

Comment: i am using chrome and type=date supported in my beowser and not only date even for button also i am getting only type=text

Comment: i checked the jffiddle but replace div with <td id="evt_date_input1"></td>
Its not working

Comment: T.J.Crowder thanks for fiddle i added div with same id and its working fine
can u explain me why its not working for <td id="evt_date_input2"></td>
and working for <td><div id="evt_date_input2"></div></td>

Comment: firefox for one doesn't support type="date" ... so input.type will be `text` ... however input.getAttribute('type') will be `date`

Comment: Siva - If you update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem, we can help you. Without that, I don't think we can.

Comment: T.J.Crowder i updated as u said can u check